# get directory name of directory containing directory

Tags: vb.net, directory, enumeration

How to get the folder name from the full path of folder?

This is file path,

```
"c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text"
```

Here **text** is the folder name.

But i want to get the folder containing **text**, that is **beta2**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`Path.GetDirectoryName` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) can be used to return ***"c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2"***, as shown below:

```
Dim filePath As String = "c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text"
Dim directory As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
```

To get just the name of the parent folder, ***"beta2"***, you can split the input and take the second last entry, given that the input is indeed accurate:

```
Dim split As String() = filePath.Split("\")
Dim parentFolder As String = split(split.Length - 2)
```

Answer (score 13):

Fri 7/09/2012 10:42 AM
io.path.getFileName(filePath) will return the folder name